# About WebCache's sd_setImageWithURL with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm using `WebCache` with swift.

When I set `String` into `sd_setImageWithURL` directly like following, it's displayed correctly.

```
imageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://imgfp.hotp.jp/IMGH/86/49/P018678649/P018678649_238.jpg"), placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly, completed: {[unowned self] (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, type: SDImageCacheType, url: NSURL!) -> Void in
    ....
```

But, I set like following, it's not displayed..

```
if let imageURL:String = shop.img {
    print(imageURL) // same as above
    self.imageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL), placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly, completed: {[unowned self] (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, type: SDImageCacheType, url: NSURL!) -> Void in
        ....
}
```

What's wrong??

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
if let strImage = "http://imgfp.hotp.jp/IMGH/86/49/P018678649/P018678649_238.jpg"{
    self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: strImage), completed: { (img, error, type, urls) in
    })
}
```

Use `imageView.image` to display wherever you want.